# Laravel Excel::store file empty after stored

Tags: php, excel, laravel, store

I uploaded this excel file: `myExceldocument.xlsx`

After uploading I want to store in a folder.

I used this method:

```php
$uploadedFile = $request->file('files')[0]->getClientOriginalName(); //it worked

Excel::store(new DeductionsImport, $uploadedFile, 'documents');
```

`'documents'` is related to filesystem.
The excel file is correctly filed in my folder called 'documents'.

The problem is when I open it, the excel file is empty!
Do you know why ?

My goal is only upload an excel document and store in folder.

Answer (score 1):

`Excel::store` is for storing exports, not saving uploaded files.

If you are simply trying to save your `myExceldocument.xlsx` to your documents folder, the request object has a simple method for it.

```
// Where 'files' is the name of the upload field in HTML.

$request->file('files')->store('documents');
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand that export ans import is related to the database only.  It work and the excel file contain data.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
$fileNameToStore = $request->file('files')[0]
Storage::disk('documents')->put($fileNameToStore, fopen($file, 'r+'));
```

work but is not the best solution because folder is filed with '' :

```
$file->storeAs('',$file->getClientOriginalName(),'documents');
```